# Displaying tasks under specific project in django

Tags: django

HI I am currently trying to develop a project management system.
I am stuck at showing tasks related to a particular project when I view project details

model.py looks like this

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    start_date  = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    due_date    = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    progress    = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=progress)
    status      = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=status)
    priority    = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=priority)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def total_projects(self):
        return Project.objects.all().count()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('projects:project_list')


class Task(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    project     = models.ForeignKey(Project, related_name="tasks", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    priority    = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=priority)
    status      = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=status)
    assigned    = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s - %s' % (self.project.name, self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('projects:add_task')
```

views.py looks like this

```
class ProjectListView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'projects/project_list.html'


class ProjectDetailView(DeleteView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'projects/project_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        projects = Project.objects.order_by('id')
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        context["projects"] = projects
        return context
```

I have tried searching the net, nothing is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so a couple of things here.

You've created a ForeignKey relation between the Product and Tasks objects, so you can just do `product.tasks.all()`.

You've slightly messed up the view though. You should be inheriting from DetailView, not DeleteView, and then you'll have access to the `object` in the context.

For example:

**views.py**

```py
class ProjectDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'projects/project_detail.html'
```

**projects/project_detail.html**

```
...
{% for task in object.tasks.all() %}
   <li>{{ task }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```